# How to create a Treeview from CSV after uploading it into a Dataset in C#?

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. I decided to try and make a program for my department that users can load a CSV and look up Serial Numbers and Names associated with them. In my program, I am importing a CSV file into a DataViewGrid and displaying it.

Is it possible to then take the information I just loaded,and display it in a TreeView?

The information in the CSV currently contains only 2 headers, but I would like to add more. The first column is a Serial Number, and the second column is a Name.

Thanks in advance for any help.

[image: This is an example of what I display]

Below is how I import the CSV.

```
     public DataTable ReadCsv(string fileName)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Data");
        using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"" +
            Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName) + "\";Extended Properties='text;HDR=yes;FMT=Delimited(,)';"))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("select *from [{0}]", new FileInfo(fileName).Name), cn))
            {
                cn.Open();
                using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    adapter.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }

    //Button Open
    private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "CSV|*.csv", ValidateNames = true, Multiselect = false })
            {
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = ReadCsv(ofd.FileName);
                dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells); //Autosize columns
                label1.Text = ofd.FileName + " Loaded"; //Label update
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Unable To Read CSV", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "**Like most people**, I am new to C#." - hugh??

Comment: csv's are built for tabular data which is why is work well with a grid.  Tree views are build for hierarchical data.  Are you converting the the tabular data to hierarchical data before trying to bind to the tree view?

Comment: TreeViews are for hierarchical data. You have hierarchical assosiations in your CSV?

Comment: It may be possible to introduce some grouping in the GridView, though. Not sure, if the "standard" one is capable of that.

Comment: @Fildor - C# was released in 2000. So in the grand scheme of things, aren't we all *new* to it? ^_^ -- we're pretty used to the pyramids by now...

Comment: @Corak Hmmm, there's some truth to that...

Comment: See for example https://10tec.com/articles/datagridview-grouping-two-recipes.aspx if that comes near to what you want. Or here: https://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html#grouping and "the original" ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-group-sort-and-filter-data-in-the-datagrid-control

Comment: My CSV does not contain any hierarchical associations. I will go back and do some more research on that. Also thanks for the article suggestions. I need to step up my google-fu game.